# JavaScript: How to extract source code of all functions in a JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree

I would like to have a list of functions of a JS code together with the sources for each function. I'm completely new in this area, I found that I need to build AST of the code and traverse it. By searching on the web I found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/function-extractor) API, but it only gives me a list of function names, how can I extract the source code of functions?

Comment: do you have the functions in a js file?

Comment: yes, I want to extract the functions of the JS files (I mean to have an array of functions' code)

Comment: and you want that source code to be a string or want to use it?

Comment: Kinda smells like an X/Y Problem. What do you plan to use this for?

Comment: @ J. Pichardo, I want to have it as a string (to take a look at blocks of the code within each function), plus again having it as an AST to do more analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `toString()` to convert the body of function into string. Try this

```
function someFunction(){
    var crazyVariable = 10.123123123;
}

someFunction.toString();
```

it will return you this `"function someFunction(){
        var crazyVariable = 10.123123123;
    }"`